# Invalid use of group function to get sum of field from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

MySql Version 5.7.34

This query is working and showing the expected result fine

```sql
SELECT
    MAX(`a`.`Start_Balance_Qty`) - SUM(IFNULL(`b`.`QTY`, 0)) as remaining
FROM
    (
        `items` `a`
        LEFT JOIN `details` `b` ON
            (
                (
                    (`a`.`item_numer` = `b`.`PARTNO`)
                    AND
                    (`b`.`deliverystatusid` = '6')
                )
            )
    )
GROUP BY
    `a`.`item_numer`
```

The result is displaying one column which displaying the remaining quantity on the inventory tables as below :

```
    | remaining |
    |    50     |
    |    60     |
    |    10     |
```

I want to have the total sum of this column to display the result as below

```
    | TotalSum  |
    |    120    |
```

I tried to add sum but it gives me error invalid use of group function.
I wrote the sum as below

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(
        MAX(`a`.`Start_Balance_Qty`) - SUM( IFNULL(`b`.`QTY`, 0) )
    ) as remaining
FROM
    (
        `items` `a`
        LEFT JOIN `details` `b` ON
        (
            (
                (`a`.`item_numer` = `b`.`PARTNO`)
                AND
                (`b`.`deliverystatusid` = '6')
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    `a`.`item_numer`
```

what's the problem here ?

Comment: You really don't need to use so many backticks in your query. You only need backticks if you need to escape language keywords.

Comment: You also have redundant parens in your `JOIN` criteria.

Comment: Grouping by `item_number` is why you have multiple rows, try removing this - and all the redundant parenthesis!

Comment: I tried both suggestions did not work & same error

Comment: @ahmedshahin Those weren't answers - just general tips for writing readable SQL.

Comment: *did not work* is not helpful - if you don't group aggregates you won't have groups in your results; demonstrate your problem with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(remaining) from (SELECT
    MAX(`a`.`Start_Balance_Qty`) - SUM(IFNULL(`b`.`QTY`, 0)) as remaining
FROM
    (
        `items` `a`
        LEFT JOIN `details` `b` ON
            (
                (
                    (`a`.`item_numer` = `b`.`PARTNO`)
                    AND
                    (`b`.`deliverystatusid` = '6')
                )
            )
    )
GROUP BY
    `a`.`item_numer` ) A
```

This should work. Use the inner results as another table and run another query above that table.

Comment: let me know if there are any errors. May be you just need to look up the syntax.

Comment: there is still error ... You have error in your sql syntax

Comment: what is the error ? can you send me your schema file so that i can check on my machien

Comment: Allow me some time to provide the schema i have to work on it . 
The error is 
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A)' at line 16

Comment: yes i was expecting syntax error but this will work if i could check on my machine with sql data

Comment: `\`a\`.\`item_numer\` A)` - the A should be outside of the `)` like `) A` as it stands for the derived table's name.

Comment: @Shadow is right. Thanks ! That's why we are facing syntax error. I'll edit answer.

Comment: @ahmedshahin Kindly mark it accepted please. Thanks

Comment: @ahmedshahin Dear ! It is up voted not yet accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

While your original query works, it already looks a little weird, because of `MAX(a.Start_Balance_Qty)`, which is essentially just `a.Start_Balance_Qty`, as you are selecting items and every item has one row in the items table containing this quantity. (The query would be more readable by the way, did you use mnemonic alias names, such as i for items and d for details.)

Now you want the sum of all item quantities, but consider each item only once. The best way to achive this is to aggreagte before joining.

Your orginal query modified:

```
select
   i.item_number,
   i.start_balance_qty - coalesce(d.sum_qty, 0) as remaining
from items i
left join
(
  select partno, sum(qty) as sum_qty
  from details
  where deliverystatusid = 6
  group by partno
) d on d.partno = i.item_number
order by i.item_number;
```

The new query:

```
select
   i.sum_qty - d.sum_qty as remaining
from
(
  select sum(start_balance_qty) as sum_qty
  from items
) i
cross join
(
  select sum(qty) as sum_qty
  from details
  where deliverystatusid = 6
) d
order by i.item_number;
```

(Or just use your original query as a base and add up the rows as shown in Muhammad Atif Akram's answer.)